# How to move a button to the right side without leaving a space | HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Just for context: I'm making a simple idle browser game. I can't seem to find a way to put the button on the right-middle of the box.

I tried position: relative and add bottom and left parameters, but the space highlighted in yellow won't go away. I'm trying to get rid of that extra space so that it matches in height with another table to the right.

Here's a visual:

[image]

And here's the HTML code

```css
.player {
  line-height: 0.6;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: azure;
  width: 49.5%
}

.interface {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <!--  useless stuff here -->
  <div class="interface">
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have set your code as a Snippet so it should display on the page. Please edit your question to include the correct HTML/CSS to recreate the issue on the snippet. Thank you.

Comment: first time in here sorry, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the button in the parent div with the blue border and give

```
position: relative
```

to the parent(.player) and give button a position absolute with right and bottom as 0
like this

```
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2mqgw73/

Answer (score 1):

You set parent to relative and its child to absolute, and position the absolute element using top, bottom, left, right and transform property to align it to your desired place.

```css
.player {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.player .interface{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <!--  useless stuff here -->
  <div class="interface">
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yup this worked, descriptive too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
.interface {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```css
.player {
  line-height: 0.6;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: azure;
  width: 49.5%
}

.interface {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
 Tons of useless stuff<br>
  <div class="interface">
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```